# Getting rid of 1px shadow on UINavigationBar with custom background image

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

I'm making a custom `UINavigationBar` with a top bar image that has a black gradient. How can I kill this 1px shadow border on the bottom?

I tried some code I found on here, but that didn't work on my device, just the simulator. Here's the code I tried.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(.LightContent, animated: false)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"TripNavigationBar2.png"), forBarPosition: .Any, barMetrics: .Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

Putting it in `viewDidAppear:`did not work either.

Can someone explain why and how I can fix it? 
[image: only on sim?]

Comment: Maybe it's a tint issue? Have you tried resetting navigationBar.tintColor ?

Comment: I don't think so @AmroShafie. Tried setting it to a 1 alpha color now, it still persist.

Comment: Hi @OscarApeland, I could reproduce the problem with an iPhone 5s, and have a fix that works for me (see my answer below). If that does not help, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have is perfectly fine.

**The problem is the background image you are using**. You either don't have an `@2x` variant, or have not added it to the project. I could reproduce the problem when using your image only in a sample project on an iPhone 5s. The problem disappeared as soon as I added a resized variant of your image to the project:

[image: Resized image]

If you add that image to your project with the name `TripNavigationBar2@2x.png`, the problem should disappear.

For completeness, I used `UIImage(named:"TripNavigationBar2")` (without the `.png` suffix), but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Not stupid at all, I think it qualifies as a bug. Glad I could help.

Comment: I filed a radar, lets see what Apple thinks. Hopefully this question and a potential fix from apple will save other developers in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest thing is assign a UIImage to the `-shadowImage` property of the navigation bar.
I still don't know swift so I write in objC :

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage  new]];
```

Using that method you are saying that every navigation bar should apply an empty image as shadowImage.
Is really weird that it doesn't work, were did you put that method? I usually call it in the app delegate didFinishLauching.
You can also try to create a 1px square image from a clear color and add it as shadow image. Here is a method that make this possible.

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithColor:(UIColor*) color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return colorImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code shows is in `viewDidLoad` in a storyboard-managed `UIViewController`, it is an extremely simple one view controller owned by one navigation controller layout. I tried what you said (by making an 1x1 see trough image in PS), that didn't work either.

Comment: Try to put that code in the applicationDidFinishLauching, and make sure that you do not use the same method with different image somewhere else

Comment: That did not work either, actually. This is starting to get hugely annoying, beginning to think that it might be a bug and not a programming fault, as it works in the simulator.

Comment: Yep could be, that's a pitty. I don't have other solution anymore, maybe try to check on different iOSes

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds
```

Comment: That did not fix the issue, sadly. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The others have exhausted all the possibilities I can think of :/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is caused by the translucent property.

The default value is YES.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Have a try, hopes it could help you.

Comment: That does not work, as my picture is an gradient to a transparent color. Doing this just makes the background white.

Comment: @OscarApeland Could you share the image file you are using?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/XexVf5l.png It's here, even if it looks invisible, its just 1px wide.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on the iPad Air with a UIImage background which left a 1px line down the left hand side. I could tell it was the UIImage by setting the background colour of the UIView behind to something loud like red. For some reason the UIImage did not fill the full image correctly.

In my case it only happened when the image I was using was an exact pixel size match for the view it was being placed inside. To fix this I edited the image and re saved it back to the same resolution. Somehow this fixed the issue for me. Absolutely no idea why and finder indicated the image was the right resolution before I edited it.

A long shot but thought it worth mentioning if your image is by chance an exact pixel perfect size for the iPhone 6 in height, width or both.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that xcode has a new debugging tool for looking at the view hierarchy exploded out in 3D. Assuming the simulator shows your issue, this debug tool might help zone in on exactly where the line is coming from. Only seems to work when running in iOS8.

Instructions are here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html